# ignoring errors in find / output

Tags: grep, find

how do I filter out permissions errors out of find / | grep foo output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think `find / -iname '*foo*'` would be a better command.  But you can redirect stderr to /dev/null to get rid of all errors.  Or redirect stderr to stdout and then filter with grep:

```
find / 2>/dev/null | grep foo
find \  |& grep 'No Such'
```

Comment: find / -iname '*foo*', definitely ;-)